# How can I open Google Play with package name? or Chrome with Url?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, google-play, google-play-services

I'd like to show my app on Google Play if it's not installed.

So, I tried this:

```
        try {
            context.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=$packageName")))
        } catch (anfe : ActivityNotFoundException) {
            try {
                context.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$packageName")))
            } catch (anfe : ActivityNotFoundException) {
                context.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.naver.com")))
            }
        }
```

This code worked fine with my old devices. But now I am trying with Samsung Galaxy20+. And it shows this error.

> ```
> To View this content, install and set up a web browsing app.
> ```

Is it the device problem that doesn't set the default browser? If it is, is there any ways to open the url with Chrome? But do I need a browser for opening the market???

[image]

Comment: Does your S20+ have a browser installed? You don't have a work profile or anything do you?

Comment: @TomBailey Yes, Chrome is already installed. And I signed in with google account.

Comment: Is it set to be the default app for web links?

Comment: does it have to? Then, if the users haven't set the default browser, there's no way to redirect to show my app or my webpage?? And yes, it is set as Default browser app.

Comment: To be honest, I think it should work without being the default. You would normally see an error like this if the browser was for some reason inaccessible (in a work profile, app is disabled), etc

Answer (score 1):

From https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play#android-app

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(
        "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.android"));
intent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @c-an It works on my Android 10 device. Did you exactly copy paste the above code (changing the package name alone)? Do you get any exception or the same dialog box that you posted in the question?

Comment: It works on some devices. But not on my Galaxy 20+.